# .Net 4.5.2 Service reference not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I currently have a WCF project in my solution that compiles with .net 4.5.2
It builds and deploys to my local IIS
The issue I am having is reference this WCF service in another project in the same solution.

I made a new solution just to be sure. There was just a class library project, .net 4.5.2 and I could connect to the service and download the metadata.

On the solution I need it to work, it only works if my target framework is .net 4.5
I have no idea why it doesn't run in .net 4.5.2

Please indicate in comments what more you need from me, as I cannot see what could be the issue. 
As I said, the service is deployed working in IIS. I can browse to it on localhost and view the svc.
Referencing the service in a different solution running 4.5.2 works, as the namespace works and I can use the code.
But not the solution I want it to work in. Only on 4.5, not 4.5.2 
It connects but the namespace doesn't exist/seem to work and I cannot see the codes and methods

Comment: You have a WCF service that is hosted in 2 different ways. One via Visual Studio and one in IIS. When this is referenced by another project, first one is working but second one is not? Am I understanding the problem correctly? Can you draw a diagram describing the deployments?

Comment: You are correct in that assumption. Project A (the main solution) uses the WCF from the solution, not working. Project B (the side app) uses the reference looking at the IIS folder, and that works. I also tried to not reference the project itself, but the IIS folder, but that didn't work either

Comment: So your 2 projects are in same solution? If yes then open 2 instances in Visual Studio. In one, run the WCF project and in another run the side app. In side app reference the running WCF project. A WCF project is not similar to DLLs. They can not be referenced by project or DLL. You need to run/host the server application then add reference to it from other projects.